# Can I convert a Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit server to an ESXi 5.5 VM?

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I need to convert a physical ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit server to VMWare ESXi 5.5 virtual machine. Found that VMWare converter 5.5.3 a) do not support trusty (release notes).  b) Converter's server side (source) scripts or utilities faults during conversion if try to convert.

Does anyone have successful experience? What are the tips to success?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hot clone? If so, you need to use [VMware vCenter Converter Standalone 4.0.1](https://www.vmware.com/support/converter/doc/releasenotes_conv401.html#introconv) I believe. First create an account at my.vmware.com, then search for "VMware vCenter Converter Standalone". On the "License & Download" tab at the bottom of all the 5.x downloads is 4.0.1.

I just tried what you're attempting. I found 4.0.1 to be the last supported version for Linux. I installed it on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop (that also has VMware player). To run after installing, issue:

**sudo /etc/init.d/vmware-converter start**

I tried to do the P2V but got stuck on the "destination" section during conversion -- it kept asking me for credentials but didn't realize it was asking for an ESXi host somewhere else on the network to "accept" the VM. I never did succeed though because I don't have hardware support for an ESXi host, and also don't know if I could alternatively use VMware Player on my laptop to "accept" the VM.

I am not 100% positive on my answer I'm just giving feedback because I just did this last week. Or tried to anyway.

See diagram about hot cloning Linux on top of page 15 here, 4.0.1 User guide: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/converter_standalone_guide401.pdf